# Eslint default rules

Tags: eslint

I have empty rules in my `.eslintrc` file but I am still getting some error messages  like "`max-len` exceeding **120** characters."

```html
{
  "env": {
    "es6": true,
    "browser": true,
    "node": true
  },
  "rules": {

  },
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "plugins": [
    "react"
  ],
  "ecmaFeatures": {
    "jsx": true
  }
}
```

The documentation says that all rules are disabled by default. I wonder why I am still getting eslint errors without my defining any rules.

1. I am using eslint version v1.10.3
2. I can get rid of the errors by explicitly disable the rule `"max-len": 0`
3. This is the ONLY configuration file I have in my project folder and I even searched to make sure there isn't even one single word of `max-len` in my project.

Are all rules disabled by default ? Where did I get the rules (e.g. max-len) from ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ESLint configurations cascade. So given a path to lint, ESLint will go up the directory structure to find config files until it either hits config with `root:true` or root directory. All the config files that will be found are going to to be merged together. There's a chance that you might have another config file somewhere in your path. In order to test that, you can run ESLint with the `--debug` flag, which will list all of the config files that are currently being used.

Comment: That's it. yes, there's another config files a few level up the directory. Thanks.